# Setting document via subpaths in firebase causes them to show up as italic?

Tags: firebase, document, data-modeling, google-cloud-firestore

if I do something like this:

```
admin.firestore().collection("collection1/doc1/collection2").doc("doc2")
```

collection1 and doc1 appear as italicized in firestore and they don't seem to be treated as if they exist.

Is there a way to let firebase know that I do in fact want to create these docs/collections as well when I add doc2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of them as a 'virtual' collection and document when they are italicized. It's because they contain and actual data at the point, only their subcollection does.

Nothing wrong with it being in that state if `collection1/doc1` is just to organize the structure.

To make it non-italicized you'll actually have to create the document explicitly.

Comment: The problem is if I reference one of the italic collections firebase seems to think it doesn't contain anything in the collection even if it does..

Comment: The collection doesn't contain any documents. I suspect you are misunderstanding something so perhaps post the code you think should do something that isn't?