# Can't retrtieve the ID of my documents (in the 'notes' collection) in Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

This is the line of code that attempts to get the documents in collection "notes". Currently for some reason in the DocumentSnapshot List only the manually added (directly in the Firebase site) documents appear, and the documents that are added through the app are ignored.

[image]

The underlined documents are the manually added ones, and they are the only ones to appear in the DocumentSnapshot List (for some reason).

[image]

!This is how I add a document to the "notes" collection.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJfKo.jpg)
This is the path.

Just to be clear the data is saved properly. The problem is that it is ignored when attempting to retrieve it.

As I said, I tried adding the data to the "notes" collection manually. When I did that, the said data *did* appear in the DocumentSnapshot List. But the data that I uploaded through the app (in the "saveNoteToFirebase" method) *did not* appear.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image. Besides that, please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully, the document IDs that don't show up in your code are shown in italic in the screenshot. That means that there actually is no document with that ID, and that the console only shows that ID because there are subcollections under it.

No snapshots for these IDs will show up in read operations. The only way to get these IDs, is to create the parent (even if you leave it empty) when you create the subcollection.

Also see:

- [Firestore query returns no documents even though they are shown in the console in italics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70539221/firestore-query-returns-no-documents-even-though-they-are-shown-in-the-console-i?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Firestore DB - documents shown in italics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137582/firestore-db-documents-shown-in-italics)
- [Why are non auto-generated document Ids are in italics in Firestore console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731794/why-are-non-auto-generated-document-ids-are-in-italics-in-firestore-console)
- [Problem with Getting List of Document/Collection from Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499104/problem-with-getting-list-of-document-collection-from-directory)
- [Setting document via subpaths in firebase causes them to show up as italic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48356669/setting-document-via-subpaths-in-firebase-causes-them-to-show-up-as-italic)